# How to find record ids with missing property ids in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

The PostgreSQL database has two tables: user_properties and properties. The properties table contains a list of all possible properties with ids (a dictionary). The user_properties table contains what properties a user has, referencing property id from the properties table.

The properties table:

```
----------------------
  prop_id | prop_name
----------------------
     1    | Email
----------------------
     2    | Phone number
----------------------
     3    | Something else 1
----------------------
     4    | Something else 2
----------------------
```

The user_properties table:

```
--------------------------------
  user_id | prop_id | prop_value
--------------------------------
    100   |    1    | asd@zxc.com
--------------------------------
    100   |    2    | 1234567
--------------------------------
    100   |    2    | 2345678
--------------------------------
    101   |    3    | *******
--------------------------------
    101   |    3    | +++++++
--------------------------------
```

I need to know which properties are missing for every user_id.
The expected result should look like:

```
-----------------------
  user_id | missing_prop_id
-----------------------
    100   |    3
-----------------------
    100   |    4
-----------------------
    101   |    1
-----------------------
    101   |    2
-----------------------
    101   |    4
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help. I've come up with the following query myself:

```
select mp.user_id, mp.prop_id missing_prop_id from
(select distinct up.user_id, p.prop_id from user_properties up cross join properties p) mp
except
select distinct user_id, prop_id from user_properties
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0f4e3/3/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`except`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-except/) as  :

```
with properties(prop_id,prop_name) as
(
  values(1, 'Email'),(2, 'Phone number'),
        (3, 'Something else 1'),(4, 'Something else 2')  
), user_properties(  user_id, prop_id, prop_value) as
(
  values(100,1,'asd@zxc.com'),(100,2,'1234567'),(100,2,'2345678'),
        (101,3,'*******'),(101,3,'+++++++') 
), t2 as
(
select u.user_id, p.prop_id as missing_prop_id
  from user_properties u
 cross join properties p
 group by u.user_id, p.prop_id 
except 
select u.user_id, 
       p.prop_id
  from user_properties u
  right join properties p
    on u.prop_id = p.prop_id
 group by u.user_id, p.prop_id   
) 
select * from t2 order by user_id, missing_prop_id;

user_id      missing_prop_id
100          3
100          4
101          1
101          2
101          4
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ca25a6b52b2a708a86b766a915f1ce2d)</kbd>

Comment: Note that those `union` queries to provide sample data can be simplified to `values (1, 'Email'), (2, 'Phone Number'), ...`

Comment: Woww, very nice feature danke @a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: Yeah :) Thanks! I've also come up with EXCEPT :) Just posted the answer.

Comment: @ArlenKeshabyan Nice. Only needs an ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve this by join...

```
SELECT DISTINCT t3.user_id, t3.prop_id FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT user_id, t2.prop_id FROM user_properties t1, properties t2) t3 
LEFT JOIN user_properties t4 ON t3.user_id = t4.user_id and t3.prop_id = t4.prop_id WHERE t4.prop_id is null
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0f4e3/2/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cross join` to generate all the rows and `left join` to filter out the ones that don't exist:

```
select u.user_id, p.prop_id
from (select distinct user_id from user_properties
     ) u cross join
     properties p left join
     user_properties up
     on up.user_id = u.user_id and
        up.prop_id = p.prop_id
where up.user_id is null;
```

Presumably, you have a `users` table so the subquery for `u` is not needed:

```
select u.user_id, p.prop_id
from users u cross join
     properties p left join
     user_properties up
     on up.user_id = u.user_id and
        up.prop_id = p.prop_id
where up.user_id is null;
```